# Можно ли TreeView заполнить коллекцией

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, observablecollection

Доброго времени суток!

Иметься таблица из БД имеющая следующую структуру

```
Tablebase
ID - Integer
NodeID - VarChar
NodeName - VarChar
nodeType - VarChar
```

Таблица сортируется запросом по полю NodeID и показывает вложенность

```
"SELECT * FROM `Tablebase` ORDER BY `NodeID`;"
1.
1.1.
1.1.1.
2.1.
2.1.1.
3.
3.1.
4.
5.
```

Можно ли сформировать коллекцию и записать высветить её в иерархическом виде или это делается как-то иначе ?

```
public class NodeTreeView {

private IntegerProperty id;
private StringProperty nodeId;
private StringProperty nodeName;
private StringProperty nodeType;

public NodeTreeView(IntegerProperty id,
                    StringProperty nodeId,
                    StringProperty nodeName,
                    StringProperty nodeType) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nodeId = nodeId;
    this.nodeName = nodeName;
    this.nodeType = nodeType;
}
// далее getter + setter + toString
}
```

Сам реализация

```
public class Controller {


        @FXML
        private TreeView<NodeTreeView> tvExplorer;

        private ObservableList<NodeTreeView> baseNodeTreeView = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


        private String sql;

        public void initialize() throws SQLException {

            Main.sqlOperation.connectToBD();

            sql = "SELECT * FROM `erelectroniclibrary` ORDER BY `NodeID`;";

            Main.sqlOperation.setQuery(sql);
            Main.sqlOperation.executeSql();

            if (baseNodeTreeView.size() >0 ) {
                baseNodeTreeView.clear();
            }

            while (Main.sqlOperation.getRs().next()) {

                baseNodeTreeView.add(new NodeTreeView(
                                new SimpleIntegerProperty(Main.sqlOperation.getRs().getInt("ID")),
                                new SimpleStringProperty(Main.sqlOperation.getRs().getString("NodeID")),
                                new SimpleStringProperty(Main.sqlOperation.getRs().getString("NodeName")),
                                new SimpleStringProperty(Main.sqlOperation.getRs().getString("NodeType"))

));
            }

            TreeItem<NodeTreeView> rootItem = new TreeItem<NodeTreeView>();

            rootItem.setValue(baseNodeTreeView.get(0));

            tvExplorer.setRoot(rootItem);
        }
}
```

Не совсем понимаю как реализовать отображение всей структуры, может использование коллекции здесь не совсем правильно? буду рад любым решениям.
Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил следующим способом

```
TreeItem<NodeTreeView> child;
TreeItem<NodeTreeView> parent;

rootItem = new TreeItem<NodeTreeView>();
child = new TreeItem<NodeTreeView>();

tvExplorer.setRoot(rootItem);

    for (Integer i = 0; i < baseNodeTreeView.size(); i++) {


        if (getPoint(baseNodeTreeView.get(i).getNodeId()) == 1) {

            parent = rootItem;
            child = new TreeItem<NodeTreeView>(baseNodeTreeView.get(i));
            parent.getChildren().add(child);
        }

        else {

            parent = child;
            child = new TreeItem<NodeTreeView>(baseNodeTreeView.get(i));
            parent.getChildren().add(child);
        }
    }


    private Integer getPoint(String nodeId) {

    Integer point = 0;
    String dot = Pattern.quote(".");
    point = nodeId.split(dot).length;
    return point;
}
```